# How to avoid access-control-allow-origin header error with AWS application load balancer

Tags: flask, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I deployed my backend application on AWS ECS and EC2, and frontend is working on another server like example.com.
I defined origin as example.com in backend using flask-cors.
It was working until multiple requests later it was throwing a access control allow origin error.
I am unable to the handle the error
my backend api is aws **Application load balancer DNS server name**